# "fields" paramether not working on Google Drive nodejs client

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I've spent a whole day trying do make this work, but the only thing i get back is the "kind", "id", "name" and "mimeType" of the files, no matters what I set on the "fields" property. Even using the example on the [Node.js Quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) didn't help, but in the [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list) it works fine...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var Q = require('q');
var google = require('googleapis');

gDriveService.prototype.listFiles = function() {
  var d = Q.defer();
  var drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3'
  });
  drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 25,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      d.reject(new Error('gDriveService: The API returned an error: ' + err));
      return;
    }
    d.resolve(response);
  });
  return d.promise;
}
```

PS: [here](https://gist.github.com/ivanwitzke/df9f34de4568dbf0c385686804fcb513) is the gist with the full code...

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
d.resolve(response);
```

Try playing with `response.files.webContentLink or`

```
response.files.webViewLink
```

or any other value from files resource.

Just observe the property hierarchy in [Files Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource).

Also, I noticed your request isn't 'authorized'.  If you check the [NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs), it's authorized:

```
function listFiles(auth) { //notice the 'auth' parameter
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth, //notice the 'auth' argument
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi.. the problem is that the only fields that comes in `response.files` are  "kind", "id", "name" and "mimeType"... so if I try any other field I get `undefined`...

Comment: do you have a way to parse the "response" object?

Comment: post the json response then. Also, try other properties like webContentLink because some files may not have webViewLink.

Comment: but then why when I use the "try this api" option [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) it works?

Comment: it's a matter of implementation, not the libraries' fault i guess. again, where's your json response? Try " files(*) " if it returns everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164826/discussion-between-anderson-ivan-witzke-and-noogui).